# Difference between boost ptr containers and normal containers?

Tags: c++, boost

What is the difference between using boost ptr containers and containers that contains smart pointers?

```
class A {} 

// ptr containers:
boost::ptr_unordered_map<int, A> p;

// containers:
boost::unordered_map<int, boost::intrusive_ptr<A>> m;
```

Comment: I'm rolling back the latest revision.  If you have a new question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  It's bad form here to edit a question to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::ptr_unordered_map` does not have the **reference-counting overhead** that would be incurred in a container of `boost::shared_ptr<A>`

It also does not require the **additional `A` object interface** that  `boost::intrusive_ptr<A>` demands.

That makes it a good solution for managing heap-allocated objects that do not require reference counting of the contained objects.

Comment: Just curious here, why do you think they didn't make a template specialization for `boost::unordered_map<int, boost::shared_ptr<A>>`?

Comment: @NickStrupat I suspect it's because that type may or may not require reference counting for the shared pointers inserted in the container.  It's not implicitly known if other pointers to the objects exist elsewhere.

Comment: When should I use reference counting?

Comment: @DrewDormann see my update. Can I change the containers to use ptr  containers in my case?